# Разная постановка ударения

Tags: фонетика

Почему говорят- возбуждено уголовное дело , с ударением на втором слоге?

Answer (score 2):

Так говорят только малограмотные сотрудники правоохранительных органов. Еще это можно назвать профессиональным сленгом